# Is there an equivalent to java @SuppressWarnings in JSP

Tags: jsp, warnings

The question is in the title : "Is there an equivalent to java @SuppressWarnings in JSP ?"

Comment: what are you trying to suppress?

Comment: I just try to clear a "type safety" warning for unchecked conversion

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, just use:

```
<%! @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") %>
```

Comment: This does actually work. I've no idea why it was down voted. I just tried it and I no longer have those obnoxious warnings.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting warnings in the code generated from a JSP (or in in-line code in a JSP), one solution is to move the problem code into a Servlet or into a utility class.  That way you can mark it up to your heart's content, and your JSP has less Java code in it.  Win-win!

Comment: That's what I intended to do in the first place, but I asked the question by curiosity...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Of course you're right, but does not help for this question.