# Eclipse Warning “List is a raw type” in a Spring jsp form

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp, jsp-tags

For example I am showing a very simple Spring form:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<form:form id="form" method="post" modelAttribute="formBean" cssClass="cleanform">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Info</legend>
    <form:label path="name">
                Name <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
    </form:label>
</fieldset>
</form:form>
```

Still I am getting 2 Eclipse warnings:

"List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized"

They are  for the line:

```
Name <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
```

Is there any way to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: This is known bug see the [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409562)

Comment: Known problem: check the link https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409562

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Juno. Upgrading to Kepler fixed this.

Comment: Upgrading to kepler didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Is there an equivalent to java @SuppressWarnings in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487715/is-there-an-equivalent-to-java-suppresswarnings-in-jsp)

Add `<%! @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") %>` to the top of your JSP should solve the problem.